# How would intergalactic travel be done in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

In a Star Trek fan fiction, I was planning to have the crew use subspace domains to travel to another galaxy, but I don't know if this is actually possible in canon. In the Star Trek universe, can subspace domains be used to travel to different galaxies?

Comment: Or that cloaking device on the Pegasus becuse it traveled thought matter its self dark matter might work tell me if I should use this for a story

Comment: May be a better fit for https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stargate has hyperdrives with variable speeds, some ships do interstellar in reasonable times, some do intergalactic

Comment: Its a star trek story has to work for star trek science

Comment: I took your question to simply ask about intergalactic travel in *Trek* (by ship, not by Q), rather than any particular method. If you rephrase it that way, it would be more on-topic for here, or if you want "can dimension X do thing Y", that would be worldbuilding.

Comment: Star Trek science is completely subservient to the needs of the writers. "Subspace domain" is as good a piece of explanatory technobabble as any.

Comment: @JoshuaFarrow I've edited your question to hopefully make it clearer, and less likely to be closed.

Comment: @Politank-Z: This is true, but some *Star Trek* technology has developed a limited degree of rigidity.  For example, you normally cannot beam through the shields.  Will this stop a determined writer?  [No](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Wounded_(episode)#Act_Five) (spoiler link!), but they will have to put in an extra line of dialog acknowledging the irregularity.  I'd say *Trek* is slightly harder sci-fi than, say, *Doctor Who* ("This is my timey-wimey detector.  It goes ding when there's stuff!").

Answer (score 10):

On Memory Alpha, it mentions that [Kelvans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelvan) came from the [Andromeda Galaxy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) on generational ships, but almost all of *Trek* has focused on the good ol' Milky Way.

You could also go anywhere when you go Warp 10/[infinity speed!](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode)), but even then the story doesn't really venture a day or two from Voyager. Likewise, Q or the Traveler also go "everywhere", but without the need for pesky ships.

Note that going into [extra-dimensional realms](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fluidic_space) and back again wasn't a revolutionary way to get home quicker. [Transporting to parallel universes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_universe) also basically maintained positions.

Looking up some other galaxies in Memory Beta, the repository for non-canon *Star Trek* works, it mentions that the [Andromeda Galaxy](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) has been lightly explored via transwarp corridor

> Both the Andromeda and Milky Way galaxies are connected by a transwarp corridor which increases the travel speed of transwarp voyages between the void, the USS Monitor during transwarp trials accidentally found its way into this corridor and was stranded between galaxies as a result.

Other "galaxy ships" (not *Galaxy*-class) were built for intergalactic exploration

> In the 2280s, Starfleet had begun to look at exploring the Andromeda Galaxy and sent several long-range starships, including the USS Magellanic Clouds, to investigate.

You could trace through more pages on Memory Beta to find something to build off of that would work for you. If you want a looser list of dimensional *Trek* techno-babble, see [parallel universe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parallel_universe).

---

Voyager, by its premise, has come across lots of ways to maybe get home quicker, and they basically all fail. Let's say you wanted to get to the Large Magellanic Cloud (160 kly) or the Andromeda Galaxy (2.5 Mly). Their normal sustained warp would do the 75 kly in 75 years, so at a normal pace it'd take 160/2500 years.

- Displacement wave from the [Caretaker Array](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Caretaker%27s_array) (75 kly in minutes(?)) could get you there in minutes/hours.
- Wormhole flavors (instant)

  - ["False Profits"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/False_Profits_(episode)): Unstable
  - ["Eye of the Needle"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eye_of_the_Needle_(episode)): Too small/travels through time
  - ["Pathfinder"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pathfinder_(episode)): Too small/intermittent
  - ["Inside Man"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inside_Man_(episode)) (geodesic fold): Lethal radiation
  - ["Counterpoint"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Counterpoint) (intermittent cyclical vortex): Short range
  - ["Q2"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q2_(episode)) (spatial flexure): Magic Q knowledge
- Transwarp flavors

  - Quantum Slipstream from ["Hope and Fear"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hope_and_Fear_(episode)), mentioned doing 300 ly/h, so would take 20 days/1 year for LMC/Andromeda. Species 116 had it working on the ["USS Dauntless"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Dauntless) while Voyager's own was unstable and [killed most of the crew](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timeless_(episode)).
  - Borg Transwarp from ["Dark Frontier"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Frontier_(episode)), did 20 kly in some unspecified time in the episode epilogue. Assuming 3 days, it's basically identical to the slipstream above. Also consumable, or that's just a side effect of some incompatibility.
- [Graviton catapult](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Graviton_catapult) from ["The Voyager Conspiracy"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Voyager_Conspiracy_(episode)): 1.5 days/23 days. Not really sustained, one jump was 3000 ly, but literally one guy built it.
- Space-time

  - ["Future's End"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Future%27s_End_(episode)), et al.: [29th century](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/29th_century) Starfleet tech.
  - ["Endgame"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Endgame_(episode)): future Klingon tech

Other series'

- [Subspace vortex](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Subspace_vortex) from Enterprise, that at 180 ly/h would take 37 days/1.5 years. Note that this is *way* faster than TNG/VOY tech despite being centuries older.

Comment: What about the dark matter barrier at the edge of the milky way galaxy

Comment: Is your question *that* narrow or do you just want a *Trek* way to go between galaxies? I'm trying to provide examples for the latter.

Comment: Well I would like it to line up with the science of the and voy and ds9 so I wanted to do my research

Comment: DS9 didn't have anything quick beyond the semi-artifical wormhole. Look at every failed or successful technology from Voyager and take one of them or technobabble a fix for it.

Comment: I have had a hard time finding any info past ds9 would you have any links I should check out

Comment: The Cytherians seem to have tech that travels pretty fast (TNG 4x19 "The Nth Degree"), but the distance portrayed (30 kly) is a bit too short for us to extrapolate to intergalactic travel.

Comment: @Kevin I extrapolated everything, so it's all fair game. I think their thing would also fall under my listed "Wormhole flavors" as "Magic Cytherian knowledge". Josh really just needs to embrace that Star Trek ships run on plot, and develop a travel method that emits interesting stories (messy mixed metaphor...)

Comment: Here's a question was crewman Daniels database destroyed or is that just floating on Enterprise and some junkyard